# Retrieving URL From Just Prior to Logout in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I am trying to obtain the last active url prior to logging a user out of my Angular 2 app, so that when they log back in it will redirect them to that component/page. The thing is, while I'm able to obtain the active url with `this.router.routerState.snapshot['url']` -- this always provides me with the result `/login` -- which is the url they're re-directed to right AFTER logout takes place. What I need to do is find a way to get the url JUST PRIOR to logout happening. I tried doing this in my logout function in my authenticationService:

```
logout()
{
    let activeUrl = this.router.routerState.snapshot['url'];
    console.log(activeUrl);
    this.apiService.logout();

    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    sessionStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    console.log('User successfully logged out');

    // Trigger event
    this.change.emit(this);
}
```

But even though the activeUrl is being console.logged before `this.apiService.logout()` is called (see order of operations in above function), I still end up getting `/login` logged to the console. Is this to be expected? How can I get around this?

EDIT: After some reflection it occurs to me now that the problem may be that I'm calling the logout() function from within the `ngOnInit` life cycle hook of my login component - so at that point '/login' is going to be the result regardless:

```
ngOnInit()
{
    this.authenticationService.getActiveUrl();
    this.authenticationService.logout();
}
```

So the pertinent question becomes: how do I capture the active URL *just prior* to being logged out?

Comment: When you `console.log(window.location.href)`, do you get the correct url?

Comment: And what about `this.router.url` value?

Comment: I get exactly the same result -- '/login' for both.

Comment: Actually, it occurs to me now that the problem may be that I'm calling the logout() function from within the ngOnInit life cycle hook of my login component - so at that point '/login' is going to be the result regardless.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterState) it states that `RouterState` contains `RouterStateSnapshot` so to me it seems that the `toString()` is called when you log it to console but you still keep a reference in your `activeUrl` which may change.

Try:

```
let activeUrl = this.router.routerState.snapshot['url'].toString();
```

Comment: No go. Exactly same result. And I believe it's already a string here.